# duplicates with connect by in oracle

Tags: oracle

```
select RP.COUNTRYID,RP.PRDCODE,
  RP.REPID,
  RP.CHANNELID,
  RP.CUSTOMERID,
  RP.DIVISION,
  RP.WWCOGS_GAUSS,
  RP.WWCOGS_SAP,
  RP.WWCOGS_BusLine,
  RP.CURRID ,
  ADD_MONTHS(to_date('01-01-'||rp.year,'DD-MM-YYYY'),level-1) KFDATE
  from 
(SELECT CP.COUNTRYID,
  CP.PRDCODE,
  CP.REPID,
  CP.CHANNELID,
  CP.CUSTOMERID,
  IP.DIVISION,
  CP.WWCOGS_GAUSS,
  CP.WWCOGS_SAP,
  CP.WWCOGS_BusLine,
  CP.year,
  CP.CURRID from
(select distinct IBC.COUNTRYID ,
       decode(ls.dmdunit,null,mwa.ProductName,ls.dmdunit) PRDCODE,
    ReportingUnit REPID,
    '99' CHANNELID,
    IBC.COUNTRYID CUSTOMERID ,
    (
    CASE
      WHEN MWA.COGSSourceCF LIKE '%Gauss%'
      THEN MWA.COGSPriceCF * MWA.ExchRate
      ELSE NULL
    END) WWCOGS_GAUSS,
    (
    CASE
      WHEN MWA.COGSSourceCF LIKE '%SAP%'
      THEN MWA.COGSPriceCF * MWA.ExchRate
      ELSE NULL
    END) WWCOGS_SAP,
    (
    CASE
      WHEN MWA.COGSSourceCF NOT LIKE '%Gauss%'
      AND MWA.COGSSourceCF NOT LIKE '%SAP%'
      THEN MWA.COGSPriceCF * MWA.ExchRate
      ELSE NULL
    END) WWCOGS_BusLine,
    mwa.year,
  IRC.CURRID
 from BAM.M_WWCOGS_AREA MWA,
  MICSTAG.M_IBP_REPUNIT_CURRENCY IRC,
  micstag.M_IBP_BDREPORTINGCOUNTRY IBC
  ,MICSTAG.M_LOCALPRODUCT_STAG LS
WHERE MWA.ReportingUnit=IRC.REPID
--and mwa.productname='FR21030390085'
--and MWA.GaussCountry='BE BELGIUM'
AND IBC.COUNTRYPLANNINGGROUP =MWA.GaussCountry 
and IBC.businessdivision=31
and MWA.COGSPriceCF <>0
  and ls.REPORTINGUNITID(+)=mwa.ReportingUnit
  and ls.IBPLOCALPRDID(+)= mwa.ProductName ) CP, micstag.M_IBP_PRODUCT IP
  where CP.PRDCODE=IP.PRDID) RP
    CONNECT BY level <= 12  ;
```

the above query is getting unwanted duplicate, if i use distinct the query is running forever. 
req. duplicate the records based on year in result set of rp
consider value of year is 2019 than 12 records should came from 1-jan-2019 to 1-dec-2019.
more than one value of year are possible

Comment: Yes no duplicate when i remove connect by level <=12 and ADD_MONTH(..) from select, but i want them in query.

Comment: We can relate the question to" how to use the column value( this case year) in connect by in oracle table ( not dual) "

Answer (score 0):

The CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12 trick works nicely with dual because that table returns one row. Things are messier when they base result set returns more than one row, because the CONNECT BY generates a product. This is why you're getting duplicates.

What you need to do is specify some additional criteria for the connection. Ideally you will have a primary key in the projection - I'm going to assume it's REPID, so if it's something different you'll need to tweak this. Anyway, you'll need something like this:

```
) RP
    CONNECT BY level <= 12 
            and rp.repid = prior rp.repid
            and prior sys_guid() is not null
```

The `prior sys_guid()` bit prevents `ORA-01436: CONNECT BY loop in user data.`

Comment: Thank-you for your feedback. we dont have any primary key on the table.

Comment: Surely there is a combination of columns in the project which could act as a primary key?